# Display `/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info` from the command line

Tags: linux, debian, acpi

On a fresh Debian/stable 9.5 installation on a MacBookPro10,1, I am trying to display acpi info from the command line.

Here is what I see:

```
$ find /proc/acpi/
/proc/acpi/
/proc/acpi/button
/proc/acpi/button/lid
/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0
/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state
/proc/acpi/wakeup
```

But `acpi` seems to see the battery anyway:

```
$ acpi -V
Battery 0: Discharging, 46%, 01:17:56 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 8460 mAh, last full capacity 7415 mAh = 87%
Adapter 0: off-line
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 17
Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 17
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 17
Cooling 3: BAT0 no state information available
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 17
Cooling 5: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 17
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 17
Cooling 8: Processor 0 of 17
Cooling 9: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 10: Processor 0 of 17
```

What am I missing from the installation to get proper battery info from `/proc/acpi` interface ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the system calls executed by `acpi` on my Ubuntu:

```
~ strace -e open,chdir acpi
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
chdir("/sys/class")                     = 0
chdir("power_supply")                   = 0
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("BAT0/current_now", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("BAT0/power_now", O_RDONLY)        = 4
open("BAT0/charge_now", O_RDONLY)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("BAT0/energy_now", O_RDONLY)       = 4
open("BAT0/voltage_now", O_RDONLY)      = 4
...
```

So it seems to be reading information from `/sys/class/power_supply/*`.

Since the functionality is provided in `/sys/class/power_supply/*` and since Debian kernel is build without `CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER`:

```
$ grep CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER /boot/config-$(uname -r)
# CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER is not set
```

You will not see anything anymore in `/proc/acpi/battery/*`